# Combining multiple php files

Tags: php

The current code provided on previous question is working. I need help to modify it so I can tell it what php files to combine.

The code below combines every .php file it finds in a directory.

(ie: Need to combine only the following pages, page1.php, page2.php, page3.php, page4.php, page5.php, page6.php, page7.php, page8.php, page9.php, page10.php, page11.php, page12.php )

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
  $code.=file_get_contents("./$filename");
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$code); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file names and they are not going to change then you can do this:

```
<?php
$files = array("a.php", "b.php", "c.php");
$comb;
foreach ($files as $k)
{
    $comb .= file_get_contents("./".$k);
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$comb);
?>
```

If you are getting them from a form submission then do something like this:

```
<?php
$files = array();
foreach ($_POST['files_to_combine'] as $k)
{
    $files .= $k;
}
$comb;
foreach ($files as $k)
{
    $comb .= file_get_contents("./".$k);
}
file_put_contents("./combined.php",$comb);
?>
```

** As a security note please make sure to sanitize your inputs if you use the second method! this code is only a proof of concept to make it simple to understand and use.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, the data is text only or pull down choices. I do rental inspections a couple days a weeks for a management company. And the boss said if I can get it to work as it does now he'll let me use it. Right now it's all on paper, 35 or more pages sometimes. Then When I get home at night I have to enter it into a spread sheet with the 100+ photo's I take and sort, and then print to PDF. I don't get paid for the extra three or 4 extra hours I spend on it both nights. So if I can get this to work I'll be happy and it will make the wife very happy also.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why I get negative on my question asking to have it modified seeing how the programmer that answered it copied it from another site.

I don't do this for a living and have no plans too. These are personal
things I try to do to make my job go easier and without paper.

So here is the answer.

```
 <?php

 $txt1 = file_get_contents('page-001.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-002.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-003.php');

 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-004.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-005.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-006.php');

 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-007.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-008.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-009.php');

 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-010.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-011.php');
 $txt1 .= "\n" . file_get_contents('page-012.php');

 $fp = fopen('newcombined.php', 'w');
 if(!$fp)
    die('Could not create / open text file for writing.');
    if(fwrite($fp, $txt1) === false)
      die('Could not write to text file.');

      echo 'Text files have been merged.';    
?>
```

Comment: just a pointer, U could use PHP_EOL instead of "\n" for those linebreaks

Comment: Thanks. I'll change that. Would that be with our without the quotes

Comment: Yes, it is a php constant. The advantage of using PHP_EOL is that it works platform independent